# To check weather the date selected by date picker is yesterday

Tags: php, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

User inputs check-in and check-out dates
I want to check weather the check-in date is not yesterday, it can be today.
&
Weather check-out date is at-least one day more than today.
(i.e starting from tomorrow but not today )
Date Format : 23-05-2015 ( dd-mm-yyyy )

Have tried converting date to string using (strtotime), but it also calculates the hours and even show the current date as previous date
 when using strtotime :(
Is there a way to do this .. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build DateTime objects and compare them.

```
<?php
$checkin = new DateTime($_POST['checkin']);
$checkout = new DateTime($_POST['checkout']);
$today = new DateTime();

if ($checkin >= $today && $checkout > $checkin) {
    // proceed to order
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see you used php class DateTime.<br/>How can i include that class in my php site.. ?

Comment: DateTime is a native PHP (>= PHP 5.2.0) class, you don't need anything to use it : ) See : http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php . When using dates, u should use it a lot, it's very convenient. For example, you can make easy date operations : `$today = new DateTime(); $tomorrow = $today->modify('+1 day'); $lastDayOfMonth = $today->modify('last day of this month');`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I can understand completely what you want. But if you just want to check if a hotel booking date interval is valid for example then here is a really simple code snippet which can help you out:

```
<?php
$checkIn = '22-05-2015';
$checkOut = '24-05-2015';

$checkInTime = strtotime($checkIn);
$checkOutTime = strtotime($checkOut);
$todayTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

if ($checkInTime < $todayTime) {
    echo 'Can not have a checkIn day in the past!';
}
if ($checkOutTime < ($checkInTime + 60 * 60 * 24)) {
    echo 'Have to stay at least one night!';
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was simple, poor me.